# Python Requests - Basic Access Authentication

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, basic-authentication

[image]

New to Python and web scraping here. I'm trying to understand the Basic Access Authentication parameter in the requests library. For example, if I am trying to use the post method as follows:

```
requests.post("www.somewebsite.com", data = some_data, auth = ('user', 'pass'))
```

What exactly is the 'user' and 'pass' parameter? Do I need to create an account for that respective website and pass in my account's username and password? I tried running my query without the 'auth' parameter and I return a 403 status code, so it is my understanding that I need to include the 'auth' parameter.

Any advice regarding this will help, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Any Api have it's own authentication process.
You mentioned Github, which requires a username and password to authenticate.
Some Api's may require some kind of access-token or stuff like that.

You can gain more information from [Here](https://blog.restcase.com/4-most-used-rest-api-authentication-methods/).

Comment: Great, thank you! So I am assuming I would need to generate a username and password, or an access-token from the website to gain access.